# How to save register post request in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

The following code works properly, registers & logins accounts.

I added a `Data.create` on the register POST requests which saves the data from register, saves properly aswell.

The issue is that after I turn off the server and on again, the data is not saved in users variable and I can't login with what I've registered earlier with.

server.js

```js
const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
initializePassport(
  passport,
  email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
  id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)

const users = []

app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    users.push({
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword
    }),
    Data.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword
    })
    res.redirect('/login')
  } catch {
    res.redirect('/register')
  }
})
```

passport-config.js

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email)
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id))
  })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

data.js (Database)

```js
var Data = sequelize.define('data', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING
});

module.exports = Data;
```

Comment: but there's an issue - what is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that after I turn off the server and on again, the data is not saved in users and I can't login with what I've registered earlier with. @Koga